# Google Apps Scripts trouble indexing values within a row

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array within a spreadsheet that has stock data.  I want to find a column number "restock value", and the row number product/sku (Row) to eventually build a custom function.  The column is indexing fine, but the  Row keeps logging 0.

I've tested a few objects within my array. I've also tried removing the column index. but no dice. still logging 0.

I've also tried removing [0] from my code. It seems that this is part of the problem, because when I log lookupRowValues without [0] I get the value of each row with their own individual brackets, when I add [0] I only log the first row.

```
function UnitsToShip(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("US");


  //Lookup Column

  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

  var lookupColumnValues = ss.getRange(4,2,1,lc).getValues()[0];

  var indexColumn = lookupColumnValues.indexOf("Restock Amount") + 1;


  //Lookup Row

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var lookupRowValues = ss.getRange(4,2,lr,1).getValues()[0];

  var indexRow = lookupRowValues.indexOf("AH-POR-DIF-WHT")+1;

  Logger.log(indexRow);
}
```

I'm testing it with a product in the array that should return 6.

Comment: It would be helpful to look at a copy of your spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function UnitsToShip(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("US");
  //Lookup Column
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var lookupColumnValues = ss.getRange(4,2,1,lc-1).getValues()[0];
  var indexColumn = lookupColumnValues.indexOf("Restock Amount") + 2;
  Logger.log('indexColumn: %s',indexColumn);
  //Lookup Row
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lookupRowValues = ss.getRange(4,2,lr-3,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var indexRow = lookupRowValues.indexOf("AH-POR-DIF-WHT")+4;
  Logger.log('indexRow: %s',indexRow);
  var restockAmount=ss.getRange(indexRow,indexColumn).getValue();
  Logger.log('Restock Amount: %s',restockAmount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but still logging 0.  I logged lr and i'm getting 70, which is the correct number of rows.  Even when I change the variable to
var lookupRowVales = ss.getRange(4,2,70,1).getValues()[0]; 

i'm still logging 0.  seems that it's a problem with the "lookupRowsValues" variable

Comment: sure https://imgur.com/a/VmmuJIU

here's the image of the array that I'm working with.  The important information starts at B4.  Column H is index correctly, but Row 9 is not.  Thanks again!

Comment: Try  it now. I made a couple of small changes.

Comment: I've made several edits so be sure you get the last one. I'm done now.